# What will happen when I delete my answer to another user's question?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

When I delete my answer to another user's question which has no upvotes or downvotes and is not the accepted answer, what will happen to my reputation? Suppose my answer has upvotes or downvotes or is accepted, what will happen?

When I delete my answer to my own question which has no upvotes or downvote and is not the accepted answer, what will happen to my reputation? Suppose my question has upvotes or down votes or is the accepted answer, what will happen?